# Fibered knots vs Heegaard genus

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds

We call a knot $K$ in a 3-manifold $M$ *fibered* if $M\backslash K$ fibers over $S^1$ with fibers $\Sigma$ and such that $K$ is ambient isotopic to the boundary of the compactified fiber $\overline{\Sigma}$.  Given a fibered knot $K$ of genus $g$, by gluing two copies of $\overline{\Sigma}$ together we get a [Heegaard surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegaard_splitting) for $M$ of genus $2g$.

Is it known whether the difference between the Heegaard genus of $M$ and the minimum of twice the genus of a fibered knot in $M$ can be arbitrarily large?

In general, are there techniques besides Heegaard genus to bound from below the minimal genus of a fibered knot in a 3-manifold?  I know that Ken Baker has worked on [counting genus one fibered knots in lens spaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510391), but I don't know of any other work in this area.

Comment: I am confused by your setup here. If $M\cong S^3$, then can't we just choose a sequence of fibered knots of increasing and unbounded genus to answer your first question positively?

Comment: @NeilHoffman Thanks for the comment, see the edit. I want to minimise the genus over all fibered knots.

Answer (score 4):

This difference can be made arbitrarily large, so that there is a manifold of Heegaard genus $g$ such that the minimum genus of a fibered knot is at least $g$. This follows from examples of [Hass-Thompson-Thurston](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/gt.2009.13.2029) of closed orientable hyperbolic 3-manifolds of Heegaard genus $g$ which have a genus $g$ oriented Heegaard splitting which requires $g$ stabilizations to become isotopic to the stabilization of the Heegaard splitting with the opposite orientation.

Now, suppose one has such a manifold of Heegaard genus $g$ which has curve complex distance $\geq 2g$ (which is essentially a corollory of the manner in which the manifolds are constructed). Suppose one has a fibered knot of genus $<g$. The corresponding Heegaard splitting of genus $<2g$ has the property that it is a stabilization of the Heegaard splitting of genus $g$ by a [Corollary 4.5 of Scharlemann and Tomova](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/gt.2006.10.593). However, the Heegaard splitting of a fibered knot is equivalent to its orientation reversal, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! One question: in the second paragraph, don't we need curve complex distance $>2g$ in order to apply Corollary 4.5 of Scharlemann--Tomova?

Comment: @magicker72: okay, correct, I fixed that. In any case, one can make the distance arbitrarily large by taking powers of the gluing map. One remark: most likely there are much simpler examples, namely lens spaces, but I wasn't sure if this is known (Ken might know a reference).

Comment: There are some complications for this problem when considering knots in lens spaces, since every lens space admits a genus 0 fibered knot, the standard unknot.  However, excluding knots of this type (say by placing restrictions a homotopy or homology class of the knot) would be a natural place to look for the type of simpler examples of knots in lens spaces you mention. Alternatively, perhaps one could consider small Seifert fibered spaces as a means of avoiding the unknot surgeries?

Comment: @NeilHoffman My definition of fibered is *integrally fibered*, ie. that the fiber surfaces are honest Seifert surfaces, not rational ones.  The standard "unknot" in $L(p, q)$ for $p > 1$ is rationally, not integrally, fibered.